# Finding the range of a function to be onto

Tags: functions

I have this function:

$ f: ( -\infty ,0) \rightarrow M , f(x)=\frac{2x+4}{x} $

Find the values of the range M that this function is onto.

I want the algebraic solution

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$f(x)=\frac{2x+4}{x}=2+\frac{4}{x}<2,\quad \text{when }x<0...(1)$$

**Added**

For all $x$ in the interval $(-\infty, 0)$ the inequality ($1$) holds.

Let $f:(-\infty, 0)\to (-\infty,2)$, in order to prove that $f$ is onto, let $y$ be in the interval $(-\infty,2)$, you must find $x$ such that $2+\frac{4}{x}=y$ and $x<0$.

Comment: So.. the values of M are $(- \infty ,2)$ ?

Comment: $M$ is a set, in this case. In my post I tell that $M=(-\infty,2)$ is the set that make $f:(-\infty,0)\to M$, as you defined, an onto function.

Comment: At the first hint, from where you took $ \lt 2 $? I mean, that 2, from where it comes?

Comment: If $x<0$ then $\frac{4}{x}$ is also less than $0$.

Comment: Oh, and $ +2 $ that makes that expression less than 2 , I understood now